# Zip through a list and get every pair of items

Tags: python, string, zip

I would like to zip through a list of strings as below

```
collections = [u'Room Designers', u'BCRF', u'House']
```

What I would like to achieve is 6 combinations of the three elements in the list -

```
("Room Designers", "BCRF"), ("Room Designers", "House"), ("BCRF", "House"), ("BCRF", "Room Designers"), ("House", "BCRF"), ("House", "Room")
```

With my code below

```
zipall = [zip(i,j) for i in collections for j in collections if i!=j]
```

I obtained:

```
[[(u'R', u'B'), (u'o', u'C'), (u'o', u'R'), (u'm', u'F')], [(u'R', u'H'), (u'o', u'o'), (u'o', u'u'), (u'm', u's'), (u' ', u'e')], [(u'B', u'R'), (u'C', u'o'), (u'R', u'o'), (u'F', u'm')], [(u'B', u'H'), (u'C', u'o'), (u'R', u'u'), (u'F', u's')], [(u'H', u'R'), (u'o', u'o'), (u'u', u'o'), (u's', u'm'), (u'e', u' ')], [(u'H', u'B'), (u'o', u'C'), (u'u', u'R'), (u's', u'F')]]
```

What would be a better way to do this? Thank you!!

Comment: You're getting single-letter combinations because you're passing two strings to `zip`, and a string is itself a sequence of characters, so zip is pulling off pairs of single characters from each string.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, indeed. I also did not realize itertools could be so powerful!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to do it the way you've written, you need to omit the final `zip` call because that will break the strings up into their individual characters and pair *those* up.

```
zipall = [(i,j) for i in collections for j in collections if i!=j]

# [(u'Room Designers', u'BCRF'), (u'Room Designers', u'House'), (u'BCRF', u'Room Designers'), (u'BCRF', u'House'), (u'House', u'Room Designers'), (u'House', u'BCRF')]
```

For these sorts of problems though, the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) library is very handy. For this specific problem, you can use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to yield all permutations of 2 elements. With permutations (as opposed to combinations), the order of the pairing matters.

```
import itertools

# Create all permutations of 2 items
output = list(itertools.permutations(collections, 2))

# [(u'Room Designers', u'BCRF'), (u'Room Designers', u'House'), (u'BCRF', u'Room Designers'), (u'BCRF', u'House'), (u'House', u'Room Designers'), (u'House', u'BCRF')]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I need. Your answer is also very thorough and helpful. Now I know two days to get what I want!! Thanks!!